# How do I check stability for a state space model by using Lyaponov function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes, jacobian, stability-theory

I have a nonlinear state space model:

$$\dot{x} = f(x, u)$$

And I have linearize that with a Jacobian matrix.

Now I got a linear state space model:

$$\delta\dot{x} = A\delta x + B\delta u$$

But the problem is that some of the eigenvalues:

$$ det(sI - A) = 0 $$

are positive.

So then I solve $P$ from:

$$ AP + PA^T + B = 0$$

And put $P$ in:

$$V(x) = x^T P x $$

So, what is next step? I want to check if the system is stable in just some state position. How can I do that?

Comment: If some of the eigenvalues of $A$ are positive, then this system is not stable.

Comment: Ok. So the Lyaponov function does what? Prove stability? But if I got all eigenvalues negative, then it's mutch better to check the stability by using $det(sI-A)=0$ then?

Comment: Lyapunov did derive two methods the direct method using the nonlinear ODE and a method that can be used after linearization. The second method is straight forward. Linearize the system and calculate it's eigenvalues. If all eigenvalues have negative real parts, then the nonlinear equation is asymptotically stable at the equilibrium point.

Comment: So Lyapunov is for checking the stability for nonlinear ODE's?

Comment: Lyapunov theory can also be used to check the stability of linear ODEs. If you know the values of $A$ and it is easy to find out the eigenvalues of $A$, then you don't have to find out a Lyapunov function to prove again. But if it is only a general form, you could use Lyapunov theory to prove its stability.

Comment: Ok. But I only need to check if the system is stable or not stable :)